# Connnect sftp using jsch and public key

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, public-key

I'm using jsch to connect sftp server from java and send a file to a specific directory

```
    private static boolean enviarCSV(String localFile) throws IOException, JSchException, SftpException {

        logger.info("Enviando fichero a maquina destino..");
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = setupJsch();
        channelSftp.connect();

        String remoteDir = Config.getParametro("wssf.conf.remoteDir");
        channelSftp.put(localFile, remoteDir + localFile);

        logger.info("Enviado con exito!");

        channelSftp.exit();

        return false;

    }


    private static ChannelSftp setupJsch() throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = Config.getParametro("wssf.conf.login.usuario");
        String password = Config.getParametro("wssf.conf.login.password");
        String remoteHost = Config.getParametro("wssf.conf.remotehost");

        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(user, remoteHost, 40020);
        jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        jschSession.setPassword(password);
        jschSession.connect();
        return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    }
```

I need to use public key in order to connect the SFTP server. I'm pretty new in security and I'm not sure how to do it, additionaly I only see examples using private keys, but I think I dont need it , do I ?

Much appreciate if you help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys come in pairs. One private, one public.

To authenticate with your public key (that you freely share), you will need to prove to the other side that you in fact also have the matching private key (because anyone could have your public key, but only you have the private one).

You do this by enrcypting or singing something with your private key - which can be verified through your public key.

So for "public key authentification" you in fact have to work with the private key as well ... and can use the examples referring to that :-)

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for answering, but then I need to work with private key and public key..., but if I only need to connect and send the file and the server is not mine, i dont understand why I need to use private... Anyway, I guess I need to use something like that : addIdentity(String prvkey, String pubkey, byte[] passphrase)
https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html

Comment: For pubkey authentication, you generate a keypair (private/public) and give the public key to the server (or the admins...). Then you use the keypair to login. The server durely doesn't allow "anybody" to upload files - so you have to prove you're you first